# Can anyone explain me how the method accepts the argument

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Below is my method level code.

```
def create_todo_lists(options={})
    options[:title] ||= "My todo List"
end
```

Here is how i am passing.

```
create_todo_lists title: ""
```

I am not able to understand how my title `arg` is used in the method. **Can anyone explain me on how the method accepts the title argument** Can anyone write an equivalent JS code for the same,  i understand `JS` better.

Comment: There is not such thing as `title` in your code. There is `:title`, and that is not an argument. It is a key of a hash with its braces omitted, which is the argument to `create_todo_lists`.

Comment: @theJava please explain what exactly you don't understand about how `title` is being used in our method. Be specific.

Comment: @Cupcake: how does the title argument passed turns into options[:title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try to analyze your question and in particular your case there are few important concepts.

- **default value**

> def create_todo_lists(options={})

`options={}` here signifies that if at all when calling this function no argument is passed, it will get a parameter named `options` which will be an emty Hash.

- **optional parenthesis**

> create_todo_lists title: ""

in this line method `create_todo_lists` is called without using parenthesis around, since parenthesis are optional in a Ruby method call, it's a valid syntax and is similar to

```
create_todo_lists(title: "")
```

- **hash with single key value pair**
  In ruby a Hash with single key-value pair also has parenthesis optional therefore in your case

> title: "" and {title: ""}

are similar.

- **two different syntax for Hash**
  Ruby has two different syntax when using symbol as a Hash key therefore in your case

> title: "" and :title => ""

are very much similar.

one more interesting concept in your scenario is

- **||= operator**

which is also pretty unique in Ruby.
This operator assigns right side value to left side variable only if value of left side variable is `false` or `nil`.

Therefore in your scenario `create_todo_lists` method is getting a Hash as argument but covering few very important concepts of `Ruby`.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is currently taking in a hash

In your example, you are currently sending in the hash

```
{ title: '' }
```

the options[:title] ||= "My todo List" is checking for the existence of the key :title, if it is there... do nothing. if it isn't, set it to 'My todo List'

You are passing in an empty string as :title, which is not equal to nil.

So your example will do nothing.

You could do:

```
create_todo_lists title: nil
```

or

```
create_todo_lists {}
```

or

```
create_todo_lists
```

All of those will result in:

```
{ title: 'My todo List' }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a optional parameter that defaults to an empty hash.

It's a little hack that's used in the Ruby world to provide a bunch of *optional* parameters at once. Very useful when using templating DSLs, this way you can add attributes to `html tags` and the like.

As for a JavaScript example, I would probably refer to this answer: [Multiple arguments vs. options object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826977/multiple-arguments-vs-options-object).  Except the options parameter is optional.