# JS Extended constructor class

Tags: javascript, class, extends

I'm learning JS, i created a class `Entity` like this :

```
class Entity {

    constructor(x=0, y=0, dx=0, dy=0, width=50, height=50, solid=false,                 
                color="black", name="entity", id=Math.random()) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.solid = solid;
    this.color = color;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;   

    entityList[id] = this;
}

UpdatePosition() {

    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
}

Draw() {

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.restore();
}

BorderCollision() {

    if (this.solid == true) {

        if (this.x <= 0) {
            this.dx = -this.dx;
        }
            if (this.x + this.width >= canvas.width) {
                this.dx = -this.dx;
            }

            if (this.y <= 0) {
                this.dy = -this.dy;
            }

            if (this.y + this.height >= canvas.height) {
                this.dy = -this.dy;
            }
    }
}

    EntityUpdate() {

        this.UpdatePosition();
        this.Draw();
        this.BorderCollision();
    }
}
```

And now, i want to extend this class in a new one called `Player` who have a new member : `canMove`

But i don't know how to do a new constructor cause when i write `constructor(canMove) {this.canMove = canMove; +}` i got an error :(

thanks ;) !

Comment: Here is a good explanation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Thanks, i did that :
lass Player extends Entity
{
 constructor(canMove)
 {
  super.constructor();
  this.canMove = canMove;
 }
}

And i got a new error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not definedPlayer @ index.html:84(anonymous function) @ index.html:145"

Thanks again for helping me ;)

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt `super.constructor`??? It needs to be `super()`

Comment: `id=Math.random()` and `entityList[id] = this;` (inside a constructor) look like bad ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are extending a class and define a constructor, you need to call `super()` if you want to use `this`:

```
class Player extends Entity {
    constructor(canMove) {
        // super.constructor(); - NO
        super(); // Yes
        this.canMove = canMove;
    }
}
```

You probably will also want to pass some arguments to `super`, and since you hardly want to duplicate the entire arguments list you probably will want to use an [options object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12826977/1048572) instead of 10 separate parameters.