# Is Object Destructuring in function parameters a good pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I've really fallen in love with object destructuring with functions.

For example:

```
var buyCoffee = function({sku, pounds = 1, roast:''}){
 ...more code
}
buyCoffee({sku:"cf-100" pounds: 3, roast: 'dark'});
buyCoffee({sku:"cf-101" roast: 'light'});
```

**Pros**

- Flexibility similar to the args object.
- Added Simplicity
- Not required to put in parameters if I don't need them.

**Cons**

- Variable names are locked all the way through.
- Currying would be much harder.(From what I can tell)
- Significant computational overhead vs traditional params ?
- Harder to test?

I'd like to know what downsides there are to this approach? Is this a good pattern to use as I grow as a developer? Just looking for some wisdom from the trenches on this. Thoughts?

Comment: The main downside I have encountered in my own time is that you don't have reference to the object that is being destructured.

Comment: *"I've really fallen in love with object destructuring with functions."* – careful with things like this. You'll end up using it where you shouldn't.

Comment: I agree, that's actually why I'm asking the question :D As to try and avoid trendy programming methods. - I noticed some votes to close, that the question lends it self to being more opinion based. How might I post this question in a way that would facilitate more factual responses? Maybe this type of question just isn't really fit for stackoverflow? Thoughts?

Comment: I just voted to close my own answer, listing it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12826977/1048572 Mentioned by @Bergi below. I think gets the heart of this issue more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Variable names are locked all the way through.

Not at all. You can easily destructure into arbitrary variables:

```
function({sku:mySku, pounds:localPounds=1, roast=''}) { … // use mySku, localPounds and roast
```

> Currying would be much harder.

There's no currying when you pass objects anyway. And currying with optional parameters is always hard.

> Potential computational overhead?

Depends on what you compare it against.

Comment: 1. Good point, about renaming parameter names, didn't think about that. 2. Yeah agreed. 3. I'd be comparing against using tradtional paramter scheme func(param 1, param 2) {}

Comment: I think [that's a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12826977/1048572) than "Should I use destructuring for option objects or not".

Comment: That's actually a way better answer to this, thanks Bergi.