# Access 2 arguments in a function out of order?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, variables, multiple-arguments

Say I have a function that has (A, B, C, D, E) arguments.
`Foo(A, B, C, D, E)`
But I don't need them all the time. Sometimes I just need A and C for example. Right now I would have to call it like this:
`Foo('beef', '', 'sour cream', '', '')`

But those blanks irritate me. Is there a way to say to make it just be `Foo('beef', 'sour cream')`?
Maybe `Foo(A='beef', C='sour cream')`?

I've tried making them optional, but as I understand it, I can't expect the program to understand I want B blank. It expects 5 arguments, it needs 5.

Comment: https://travishorn.com/using-the-options-object-js-pattern-221f083aadbc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826977/multiple-arguments-vs-options-object

Comment: Use an options object instead of arguments (as stated above)

Comment: *"`Maybe Foo(A='beef', C='sour cream')`"* - You're close actually, but the syntax is slightly off. You can use multiple arguments, with default values, placing optional ones at the end of the list (unless they're _all_ optional), or a single object with keys, `{a: 'Beef', c: 'Sour Cream'}`, etc.

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate the time. I hope I didn't waste yours. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name them like this:

```js
function foo({A, B, C, D, E}) {
}

foo({A:3, D:5})
```

What we're technically doing here is passing an object, and using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the properties of the object into local variables.

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate the time. I hope I didn't waste yours. Thank you so much!